# How portable (or not) is using SQLLiteral("NOW()") in web.py DB INSERTs?

Tags: mysql, sql, portability, python-2.7, web.py

I know this works fine if my database is MySQL. And maybe others.

```
seq_id = db.insert('mytable', first="Bob",last="Smith",joined=web.SQLLiteral("NOW()"))
```

Well, right now, the database customers will use *is* MySQL, but it may not be the case in the near future. How can I ensure I won't get headaches if the customer decides it has to work on Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server and whatnot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` [is synonymous](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) with `NOW()` and standard SQL so you might as well use that in preference.

Comment: Nice! What's "more standard," with or without parentheses? Or are both equally so?

Comment: @JCCyC - Without parentheses. In SQL Server you don't get the choice.  It is an error to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Answer (score 1):

Its not. `Now()` won't work in either SQL server or Oracle.

Its also probably not worth worrying about it at that built-in function level since there's lots of other problems you encounter before that.

For example this only works on MySQL even though it doesn't use built in functions

```
SELECT a, MAX(b), c
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
       a
```

Your best bet is to make sure your data access is separated cleanly from the rest of your code if you're really worried about it and build up a new data access layer for each Database you care about.